# Know when CCScene is shown after scene on top of stack is popped

Tags: cocos2d-x, ccscene

Using `cocos2d-x, say I am on Scene 1 and I add a new scene (Scene 2), but I later pop that scene:

```
CCDirector *pDirector = CCDirector::sharedDirector();
pDirector->popScene();
```

How do I know when Scene 1 has appeared again? Is there any `sceneDidAppear` method or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCScene is derived from CCNode, therefore you can override `onEnter()` and `onExit()` method to know when a scene is pushed or poped.

Comment: But would I implement the `onEnter()` method in my class? I tried and I get the error "Out-of-line definition of onEnter does not match and declaration"

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Vikas Patidar answear : you can override `onEnterTransitionDidFinish()` - this will fire after the transition animation is complete. Docs : [link](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.1rc0/d3/d82/classcocos2d_1_1_node.html#a9ecc243090bd42aa514f0df65848f588)

Comment: Where do I override this? I tried in my class and I get an error.

Comment: What kind of error? It has to be in a subclass of `Node`. I just tested it and it went fine.